# Configuring Wildfly standalone "<remote-naming/>"

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly

Looking for examples of how to configure a Wildfly server to be very simple standalone JNDI namespace server.

I would like to specify value pairs so that our external java applications can access and use the defined resources using JNDI API's.

From the [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-GlobalBindingsConfiguration) it is clear that I have to use the  XML tag.

> Remote JNDI Configuration
>
> The Naming subsystem configuration may be
>   used to (de)activate the remote JNDI interface, which allows clients
>   to lookup entries present in a remote WildFly instance.
>
> Only entries within the java:jboss/exported context are accessible
>   over remote JNDI. In the subsystem's XML configuration, remote JNDI
>   access bindings are configured through the  XML
>   element:
>
> `<remote-naming />`

But what isn't clear is HOW to use it, I cant find any examples anywhere.

If I had the following object:

String: MyFirstProperty

How do Insert this into the `<remote-naming />` tag so that Wildfly makes it available for me to retrieve?

Comment: Please explain something for how to configure <remote-naming />, as currently i am facing the same problem